# Best way of using malloc and realloc

Tags: c++, malloc, realloc

I'm pritty new to using malloc and realloc and I have a few questions.

Question 1.

The game I am making allows you to create your own spaceschip, knowing this I was wondering is it better to realloc twice the ammount of the current memory which is the standard. Or do something along the lines of reallocing 100 extra spaces for the needed vertexes?
I my self think the seccond option would be better but maybe there is something I'm not aware of.

Question 2

If I have a malloced array of squares[20] [4] How do I realloc it to a size of squares[100][4]? Do I realloc the 1st array to 100 and then malloc 20-99 with 4 new spots?

Question 3

Right now something strange happens when I realloc my data. If I put down a break point everything goes fine but if I let the code work all at once it crashes. So I'm guessing there is a memory leak. Right now this is my realloc code.

```
unsigned char *temp =( unsigned char* ) realloc(realSpaceship, gridSize*sizeof( unsigned char ));
if(temp != NULL)
{
    realSpaceship = temp;
    //free(temp); Line is now deleted at the advice of the helpfull people here.
}
else
{
    //error
    printf("realloc error\n");
    free(realSpaceship);
}
```

I figgured freeing temp was a good idea but it just couses the code to crash at a different location.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I just realised the problem is not with the realloc but somewhere else.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

A litle extra information.
I'm using c++
And I'm also using glm

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?  In C++, `malloc` is often something people have to *un-learn* after learning it.

Comment: Is `new`, or `new[]`, or `std::vector` an options?

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm using c++, But why do I need to unlearn malloc?

Comment: When you're freeing temp, you're freeing the memory temp points to.  Since you set realSpaceship to temp, you've also freed the memory realSpaceship points to.  If realloc is successful, you will want to free realSpaceship before you set it to the value of temp.

Comment: Can you show minimal code sample that can be compiled to reproduce error?

Comment: @andre I never used new for anything but making classes So I'm not sure. Also i'm using glm:: so no I'm no longer using std::vectors

Comment: +1 for using `realloc` correctly. Most people just assign the result directly into the original pointer, which will leak memory if `realloc` fails.

Comment: @alexrider If I comment out the Realloc code there is no error. And no if I where to give all the code for minimum compilation I would need to uploads thousands of lines as my code is build up in layers and this is the top layer and thus requirs almoost everything.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you ^^, but apparently I am still doing something wrong becouse I do get an error becouse of it. Do you have anny idea to why this is?

Comment: Well, yes, as others have said: don't free `temp`; doing that releases the memory that you just allocated.

Comment: @RoyHeijmans You absolutely don't *need* to unlearn `malloc` - it would be incorrect for me to assert such a strong claim - but it wouldn't be unusual for you to discover why [`new` superseded `malloc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) or how `std::vector` makes these tasks easier still.  We can [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) if you want to discuss it.  I don't want to distract from your question.

Comment: @RoyHeijmans declaraion of realSpaceship could help a bit. Btw gridSize*sizeof( unsigned char ) is the same as gridSize, since sizeof char is always 1

Comment: Incidentally, freeing something twice is not a memory leak. A memory leak occurs when you don't free something ever.

Comment: @inca Oke I am no longer freeing temp when the realloc succeeds. But are you saying I should free realSpaceShip before I use the realloc?

Comment: @RoyHeijmans No, you should free realSpaceship after using realloc but before setting realSpaceship = temp

Comment: @inca Could you maybe post a code sniped? Becouse when I try freeing the realSpaceschip before realSpaceschip = temp my code crashes.

Comment: @RoyHeijmans My mistake, it seems that realloc will either free the original memory or reuse it if space is available, so it's not necessary to free it at all if it is successful.

Comment: @inca Oke thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, avoid using `realloc` multiple times. `malloc` once and stick with that until you run into an extreme case, then `realloc` (but even then, avoid it!)

The main reason for this is debugging and testing. If the program fails at `realloc`, it can be for multiple reasons... and most of it comes from the OS. (i.e. not enough memory, trying to use memory just freed, etc.) Those are tough bugs to reproduce and debug.

Do a little math, calculate the max you will need for your use case and `malloc` that. Move onto coding other stuff. Debugging `realloc` errors are no fun.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a few remarks and a question.
I'm using a build grid say 8*8*8 and when a player upgrades this grid it becomes 16*16*16 and thats what the realoc does. Seeing the players can upgrade their grid quite a bit I don't want to malloc huges ammounts of space at the start if it's not nessesary.

Also the realloc it self 'works fine' as it never comes into the else but I seam to get a memory leak though. Are you still saying drop the entire realloc and rather do a free on the old malloc and create a new malloc?

Comment: `realloc` is essentially the same as doing `free` and then `malloc` again, but it might keep the same pointer (IF the OS can give you a contiguous block of memory from the same address.)

memory usage at max is: 4,096 (16^3), which is 4MB. How often does your player upgrade? If it's very often, you might as well just `malloc` 4MB from the beginning. 512 (8^3), which is 512kB is a lot less than 4MB, so I do see your point, but if you're players will go from 512KB to 4MB almost all of the time, it's better to just stick with 4MB from the beginning and avoid the memory leak of `realloc`.